# QScrollArea do not resize according to set size policy

Tags: resize, qscrollarea, pyside6, qsizepolicy

I am not able to use the whole `QDialog` space for my `QScrollArea`. I set the `QSizePolicy` and `setWidgetResizeable(true)` , but with no results.

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(scrollArea, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

dialog.setLayout(layout)
dialog.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The `QScrollArea` do not want to resize to whole `QDialog`.

[image]

Comment: That size policy is the exact opposite of what you want, remove it. Also, remove the alignment argument in `addWidget()`.

Comment: Note that `setWidgetResizable()` has absolutely nothing to do with what you're referring to, as it's a setting for the resize behavior of the *content* of the scroll area. Read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) to understand its purpose and usage.